# iOS 12 Xcode 10 application:openURL:options: Crash

Tags: objective-c, crash, xcode10, openurl, ios12

I recently noticed some issues with my app causing a Warning when uploading  to the Appstore:

***Invalid Document Configuration*** - Document Based Apps should support either the Document Browser (UISupportsDocumentBrowser = YES) or implement Open In Place (LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace = YES/NO). Visit https://developer.apple.com/document-based-apps/ for more information.

My app responds to a custom extension set in its plist 'Document Types' and worked fine up until iOS 12/Xcode 10.

When adding 'Supports opening documents in place' to YES in the .plist and 'Supports Document Browser' to NO it crashes with this message:

'Application has LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace key, but doesn't implement application:openURL:options: on delegate'

My app supports iOS 8 and higher, and worked fine responding to:

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

in my AppDelegate.

When I add the new

```
- (void)openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenExternalURLOptionsKey, id> *)options completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success))completion
```

it still crashes with the error above..

Comment: Did you implement `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options;` as stated bu the crash error message? That's not the one you implemented.

Comment: Let me check this..

Comment: Jep, my bad.. this works, however it created a new issue... When tapping the file from iCloud drive it now gives me an 257 (access denied) error.. Where as in previous iOS (<12.0) it worked fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

add this in your app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options {
    return YES;
}
```

since ios 12 it is required if you also added **LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace** in your info.plist